# Set onclicklistener for MapView using open street map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

For a school project I have to create an application using some map (google maps or openstreetmap). My choice is to use OpenStreetMap because it's free.

So I have a form, in this form I need to click on a map to get the long/lat I want.

But I don't know how to set the onclicklistener correctly.

This is my activity :

```
package fr.miage.voyage_voyage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import org.osmdroid.events.MapListener;
import org.osmdroid.events.ScrollEvent;
import org.osmdroid.events.ZoomEvent;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class FormEtape extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    EditText et_nom;
    TextView et_date, et_long, et_lat;
    IMapController mapController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_etape);
        et_nom = findViewById(R.id.edit_nom_etape);
        et_date = findViewById(R.id.edit_date_etape);
        et_long = findViewById(R.id.edit_long_etape);
        et_lat = findViewById(R.id.edit_lat_etape);
        Configuration.getInstance().load(getApplicationContext(), PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()));
        //Configuration.().load(getApplicationContext(), PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()));
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.map_form_etape);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK); //render
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //zoomable
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(43.650, 7.00517);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(18.0);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
        




    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }
}
```

and there is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FormEtape">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nom de l'étape"
        android:id="@+id/edit_nom_etape"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_nom_etape"
        android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:id="@+id/edit_date_etape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_date_etape"

        android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Longitude (Appuyez sur la carte à l'emplacement souhaité)"
        android:id="@+id/edit_long_etape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_long_etape"

        android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Longitude (Appuyez sur la carte à l'emplacement souhaité)"
        android:id="@+id/edit_lat_etape"/>


    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_lat_etape"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/map_form_etape"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_addEtape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/map_form_etape"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found by myserlf, here is the solution if someone else need :

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(new MapEventsOverlay(new MapEventsReceiver() {
            @Override
            public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {
                et_lat.setHint(String.valueOf(p.getLatitude()));
                et_long.setHint(String.valueOf(p.getLongitude()));
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p) {
                return false;
            }
        }));
```

Comment: Quite good. Full tutorial here: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5#16-handling-map-events